# What is this section in websites called?

Tags: html, css, graphics

Apologies for the vague title, as I don't know how to describe it without visual examples. I want to ask a question about a popular section/component I see all the time on websites. This image shows what I mean.

[image]

The website I took this from is https://emol.work/
In the context of that website, the component I mean divides the front page into 4-5 sections, with differing colors. What is this section/component called? or, if there is such a place, could you point me to a site/resource that explains popular components in websites/web development?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to the site. Right click on the front page, select inspect. You will see it is a div called wrapper with section tags inside

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a programming question as so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried asking in other places, but as i have not yet received a question earlier, this is one of the places i remember, so i went asking here. Apologies for this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be a rotating banner or front page carousel, I'm not an expert but here's a link that may help you further and hopefully answers your question:

[https://www.artonicweb.com/learn/web-design-trend-rotating-banner/#:~:text=A%20rotating%20banner%2C%20also%20called,Front%2Dpage%20Carousel](https://www.artonicweb.com/learn/web-design-trend-rotating-banner/#:%7E:text=A%20rotating%20banner%2C%20also%20called,Front%2Dpage%20Carousel)

Comment: There is no carousel on that site. It is just a set of divs with sections inside

Answer (score -1):

May this help you: "On the web the hero section is typically a prominent image, slider, text or similar element that has pride of place at the top of your homepage layout and possibly subsequent pages. It is front and center and in your face"

Comment: where do you find this?